# How to add another entity type to Search API multiple types index?

Tags: 7, search

I created a multiple types index using Search API. Now I would like to add another entity type to it, but it's not possible. Is there any solution? I really would like to avoid recreating the index.

[image: Entity types selection form]

Comment: It seems, that this issue might be related to this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2632880

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper answer, more like a workaround:

1. Load index.
2. Delete it.
3. Mark it as new.
4. Change the datasource settings.
5. Save it again.

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/2632880#comment-11208443